# CSV File Comma Insertion

Tags: python, csv

I'm a complete newb with Python so please excuse my ignorance. I'm trying to read items in a csv file and output the values with a comma in between (and no comma at the end).

My csv file (test.csv) is as follows:

```
Test
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

and the code I'm currently using is:

```
from csv import DictReader
with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
       print('`'+row['Test']+'`,')
```

This returns the following:

```
`AAA`,
`BBB`,
`CCC`,
```

Is there any way to have the comma remain after AAA and BBB, but not after CCC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
from csv import DictReader
with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
       temp = '`'+row['Test']+'`,'
       print(temp[:-1])
```

OR in case you like to read in as df then

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Now, you run df.

pl refer: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from csv import DictReader
with open("test.csv") as read_obj:
   csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
   for row in csv_dict_reader:
      print('`'+row['Test']+'`,'[:-1])
```

You can try this as well, this will print till second last character. So basically every last occurrence of comma will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to modify what you have to do what you want is to store the values and then you can use [`",\n".join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the list.

```py
from csv import DictReader
data = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
       data.append(row['Test'])

print(",\n".join([f"`{item}`" for item in data]))
```

If you had a long list or a more complicated CSV, then you could take advantage of [`print("sometext", end="")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to avoid the new line character. Then you can start each subsequent row with `print(',')` which will also provide you with the `\n` character.

```py
from csv import DictReader

first = True
with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        if not first:
            print(',')
        print(f"`{row['Test']}`", end='')
        first = False
```

If your CSV is just a single column, you could use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to grab the lines, slice off the first line with `[1:]` and then use the same join pattern on the remainder of the data.

```py
from pathlib import Path
data = Path("test.csv").read_text().splitlines()[1:]
print(",\n".join([f"`{item}`" for item in data]))
```

Finally, as previously mentioned, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) can be used to read the CSV and then you don't have to worry about the first line.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(",\n".join([f"`{item}`" for item in df['Test'].values]))
```

All of these methods yield the following:

```
`AAA`,
`BBB`,
`CCC`
```